# Why was this flag rejected?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242310/dota-2-6-85-lag-spikes/245975#245975) as "Not an answer", and it was simply "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". Is it a mistake or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was declined because it's an answer to the question, with the answer being that a game update fixed the problem:

> So the newest update fixed the problem and the spikes went away. Thank you for trying to help.

Update your game is a perfectly valid answer, especially in a case where it actually solves the problem.

Comment: Fair, I hadn't considered that.